# Auditing for single site and a single list

Tags: auditing

I have been tasked to report on the number of site visitors and opening of items in single calendar list.

having already discovered that I should enable auditing for the list in question I went ahead and enabled it. However, how do I enable auditing for the single site instead of the site collection? And finally where do I view those reports?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can turn on SharePoint auditing on one list or site, but it cannot be done on using UI. You can turn on it using Server Side Object Model `SPAudit` object with C# code or PowerShell script, like is described here http://spuser.blogspot.com/2011/10/as-part-of-my-series-on-sharepoint.html

When you turn on auditing on list or site it also can be viewed only programmatically (by C# or PS again) using `SPAuditQuery` object, like is described here http://spuser.blogspot.com/2011/10/spaudit-how-to-read-from-audit-log.html